# How to pass variables/objects from action listener to driver class?

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I have those to classes: the main and GUI. In GUI there is actionListener which gathers information from user interface panel. How can send these variables to driver class, to execute everything there? I need to add them to infinite loop to draw a moving object, drawing methods are in other class. GUI has extended frame

here are the classes:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUI extends Frame implements WindowListener,ActionListener {
 JLabel name1  = new JLabel("Name");
 JLabel color1  = new JLabel("Color");
 JLabel diam1  = new JLabel("Diameter");
 JLabel dist1  = new JLabel("Distance");
 JLabel speed1  = new JLabel("Speed");
 JTextField name2 = new JTextField();
 JTextField color2  = new JTextField();
 JTextField diam2  = new JTextField();
 JTextField dist2  = new JTextField();
 JTextField speed2  = new JTextField();

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
dispose();
System.exit(0);
}
double distance;
int Speed;
double diameter;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
createVariables();
}
public void createVariables(){

try {
      distance = Double.parseDouble(dist2.getText());
      Speed = Integer.parseInt(speed2.getText());
      diameter = Double.parseDouble(diam2.getText());
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException i) {
    }   
    Planet cP = new        Planet(name2.getText(),distance,diameter,color2.getText(),Speed  );
    Main plnt = new Main(cP);
}

public void createFrame1(){
addWindowListener(this);
setLayout(new GridLayout(6,6,5,5));
JButton mygt = new JButton("Add planet");
mygt.addActionListener(this);
name2.setText("belekoks");color2.setText("RED");diam2.setText("30");dist2.setText(" 60");speed2.setText("2");
add(name1);add(name2);add(color1);add(color2);add(diam1);
add(diam2);add(dist1);add(dist2);add(speed1);add(speed2);
add(mygt);

}
public GUI(String title){
super(title);
createFrame1();
}
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {}
}
```

and Main:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
public class Main{
/**
 * @param args
 */

public Main(Planet name){
    super(name);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
SolarSystem system = new SolarSystem(300, 300);
GUI p = new GUI("New Planet");
p.pack();
p.setVisible(true);
Sun sun = new Sun("Sun", 0, 90, "YELLOW", 0);
Planet venus = new Planet("Venus",70,15,"ORANGE",2);
Planet earth = new Planet("Earth",100,20,"BLUE",1);
Moon moon = new Moon("Moon",earth.dist,5,"GRAY", 1, 30, 3);
Moon[] moons = new Moon[100];
moons[0] = moon;
Planet[] planets = new Planet[100];
planets[0] = earth;
planets[1] = venus;
Random rG = new Random();
Asteroid[] asteroids = new Asteroid[100];
for(int i=0; i<100;i++){
    Asteroid Asteroids = new Asteroid("Asteroid",     rG.nextDouble()+rG.nextInt(10)+45,rG.nextDouble()+rG.nextInt(10),"DARK_GRAY",rG.nextInt(360        ), 1);
    asteroids[i]=Asteroids;
}   

/*LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
for (int i=0;i<1;i++){
    list.add(moons[i]);
}
for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
    list.add(planets[i]);
}
for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
    list.add(asteroids[i]);
}
for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
    list.add(sun);
}

for(int y=0;y<2;y++){
    planets[2].move();
    planets[2].drawOn(system);
    system.finishedDrawing();
}

    for (int i=0; i>=0; i++){
    sun.drawOn(system);

    for(int y=0;y<3;y++){
        planets[y].move();
        planets[y].drawOn(system);
    }

    for (int y=0; y<100; y++){
        asteroids[y].move();
        asteroids[y].drawOn(system);
    }
    for (int y=0; y<1; y++){
        moons[y].move();
        moons[y].drawOn(system);
    }

    system.finishedDrawing();
    }
*/
}
}
```

i don't expect you to look through whole code, but the main thing is that i get variables in actionListener in GUI and i want to pass them to main in order to create an object which I could draw later.

planet class creates an object:

```
public class Planet extends CosmicEntity {
public Planet(String name, double distance, double diameter, String col, int speed)    {
    super(name,distance,diameter,col,speed, 0);
}
}
```

and CosmicEntity class which holds all the variables and methods to draw a planet from passed variables (super(name,distance,diameter,col,speed, 0)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what you need based on the information provided, but I think that you don't want to use an infinite loop, not for your GUI.  Most simple animations can be easily driven by a Swing Timer.

As for your other problem, a the general rule is that objects can call methods of other objects if they have a valid reference to the other object.  How to do this for your project will depend on your code. Often we pass references of one object to another though as a method or constructor parameter.  For instance,

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FooMain {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      FooNonGui nonGuiReference = new FooNonGui();
      FooGui fooGui = new FooGui(nonGuiReference);

      fooGui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      fooGui.pack();
      fooGui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      fooGui.setVisible(true);

   }
}

class FooGui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
   private FooNonGui nonGuiVariable;
   private int counter = 0;

   public FooGui(FooNonGui nonGuiParameter) {
      super("GUI");
      this.nonGuiVariable = nonGuiParameter;
      JButton button = new JButton("Button");
      button.addActionListener(this); // I hate doing this, but for brevity's sake...
      add(button);
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      nonGuiVariable.nonGuiMethod(counter);
      counter++;
   }
}

class FooNonGui {
   public void nonGuiMethod(int counter) {
      System.out.print("In non-GUI method.  ");
      System.out.println("counter is " + counter);
   }
}
```

I suggest that you give us more information so that we can be more knowledgeable about your problem and give you better help.  This link may help:  [Smart Questions](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Edit A:  What are you adding your planets to?  The SolarSystem object?  Whichever class it is, likely will have or should have a public addPLanet(Planet planet) method.  If SolarSystem, then you'll want to pass a reference to this object into your GUI class similar to what I do above.

Comment: well, there is drawOn method which gets the parameters and draws a planet as given. the planet is drawn on that frame (solarSystem). I want to get those parameters from user and draw them on the same solarsystem frame.

Comment: But what collection holds all the Planets?  Does the SolarSystem class have an ArrayList<Planets>?  Do any classes have an addPlanet(Planet) method?

Comment: if i understand you, nothing holds planets, its just and object with parameters which, passed to solarsystem creates a graphical image.

Comment: Something has to hold them, but it looks like it may be held in Main class in an array Planet[] planets = Planet[100].  So perhaps Main needs an addPlanet(Planet) method that the GUI can call.

Comment: Given your code above, it's hard to say as I still don't have a feel as to how your program fully works.  I don't see how you've set up an animation or how the animation will move the planets (assuming that's what it does), or how the drawing portion will iterate through the planets to draw them.  If you're still having problems, you will need to give us more details, a lot more details.